# Bootstrap 3 doesn't render select element in modal window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using BT3 with a modal window (remote data).
Why BT3 doesn't render select input element from remote content (show.php).
Select element looks normal. I need to have it like from BT3 style.
The same issue are with checkbox elements.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="show.php" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te"></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

show.php:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">TEST</option>
<select>
```

Comment: At first glance i'll say do you have called CSS bootstrap file in show.php?

Comment: no, only in main index.html where is <a data-toggle="modal" href="show.php" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a> and rest code..

Comment: AFAIK, [Bootstrap modals don't support external pages](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: could it be? It seems to me that I saw somewhere already modals that are loaded from remote data and have rendered elements

Comment: here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/cp67J/  but remote page loading again BT3... is there any other way to do that without loading BT3 in remote page?